# Rails 4: what's wrong with this scope?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

In Rails 3.2 this worked fine:

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :brands
  ...
  scope :branded, ->(b) { includes(:brands).where('brands.id in (?)', b.id) }
```

Other end of the relationship:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :components
```

But I'm upgrading to Rails 4 and it breaks with this message:

```
Unknown column 'components.brand_ids' in 'where clause'
```

What's the problem here?

**UPDATE**

I haven't made the switch to strong parameters yet, and I'm using the `protected_attributes` gem. Could that be the cause of all this?

Comment: The error is occurring on that exact line? Why are you performing an `IN` query for a single `id`? Just do `where("brands.id = ?", b.id)`

Comment: Yeah, not sure why I was doing that. Problem still exists with that line though.

Comment: Please post your `has_many` and `belongs_to` declaration of your `Component` and `Brand` models. Furthermore check that you run all pending migrations.

Comment: can you post the full error stack along with model files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the branded scope is trying to do, but with the assumption it is to find components that are have a brand X, `Component.branded(Brand.find(X))`

Maybe try this:

```
scope :branded, ->(b) { joins(:brands).where(Brand.arel_table[:id].eq b.id)}
```

Comment: So this seems to fix it, but I get a similar error for another `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. Is this a common Rails 4 issue?

Comment: Not sure if it's common for everyone, but I do know that after rails 4.0 I converted all my queries to arel_table that would have use a string in the query. https://github.com/camertron/arel-helpers is helpful so you don't have to call `arel_table` every time, you can just use Brand[:id] or Component[:title] etc.

Comment: Would love to know why this is necessary, but it's working now. Thanks for your help!